# word frequency distribution

Tags: javascript, strings, hash-map

`wordList` is an array of non-empty strings ("words"). The following code I have written with the purpose of obtaining a Map, containing the unique words and their respective count:

```
for (let p = 0; p < wordList.length; p++) {
  const word = wordList[p];

  if (wordMap.has(word)) {
    wordMap.set(word, wordMap.get(word) + 1); //increase frequency of word
  } else {
    wordMap.set(word, 1); //add word
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to obtain this frequency distribution. Although the code seems to be working, feels a bit awkward (I am aware of the existence of the reducer(), but I have difficulty figuring it out).

If possible, I'd Like also to know how to make this case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General review points

- Rather than use a `for(;;)` loop use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)  loop as you dont need the idx `p` for anything but indexing the word array.

  ```
  for (const word of wordList) {
  ```
- You don't need the comments as what is happening is obvious in the code.
- You can combine the get and set into one expression by using the [?? (Nullish coalescing operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to check for undefined.

  ```
  wordMap.set(word, (wordMap.get(word) ?? 0) + 1);
  ```
- Always create functions rather than flat code. Even when only showing example code.

### Reducer

> *"... (I am aware of the existence of the reducer(), but I have difficulty figuring it out) ..."*

Is not needed in this case but can be use if so desired. (See last rewrite)

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) a reference if needed.

### Rewrite

There are several ways you can write the function

```
function mapWordCounts(words) {
    const counts = new Map();
    for (const word of words) { counts.set(word, (counts.get(word) ?? 0) + 1) }
    return counts;
}
```

Or using [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
function mapWordCounts(words) {
    const counts = new Map();
    words.forEach(word => counts.set(word, (counts.get(word) ?? 0) + 1));
    return counts;
}
```

Or with a reducer in an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will save the need for the return token as return are implied in arrow functions with out a delimited `{}` code body. This only works because [Map.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) return the map when called.

```
const mapWordCounts = words => words.reduce(
        (counts, word) => counts.set(word, (counts.get(word) ?? 0) + 1), new Map()
    );
```